# Unit test of Spring MongoDB returns null

Tags: java, mongodb, junit5

I'm trying to Unit test my MongoDB-based Spring Boot application, and I'm getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "blueprint.model.Garage.getCarModel()" because "savedGarage" is null` error. The code is down below:

My Service:

```
 @Service
public class GarageService {

private final GarageRepository garageRepository;

@Autowired
public GarageService(GarageRepository garageRepository) {
    this.garageRepository = garageRepository;
}

public void addToGarage(Garage garage) {
    Optional<Garage> garageOptional = garageRepository.findByCarModel(garage.getCarModel());
    if(garageOptional.isPresent()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("This Car model is already in our garage!");
    }
    garageRepository.save(garage);
}

public List<Garage> showOurGarage() {
    return garageRepository.findAll();
}

public void deleteFromGarage(String id) {
    boolean exists = garageRepository.existsById(id);
    if(!exists) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("A car with id " + id + " is not in our Garage.");
    }
    garageRepository.deleteById(id);
}

public void updateCar(String id, String carModel, Integer HP, Integer year, String designer) {
    Garage garage = garageRepository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException(
                    "A car with the id " + id + " is not in our Garage."));
    if(carModel != null && carModel.length() > 0 && !Objects.equals(garage.getCarModel(), carModel)) {
        garage.setCarModel(carModel);
    }
    if(HP != null && !Objects.equals(garage.getHP(), HP)) {
        garage.setHP(HP);
    }
    if(year != null && !Objects.equals(garage.getYear(), year)) {
        garage.setYear(year);
    }
    if(designer != null && designer.length() > 0 && !Objects.equals(garage.getDesigner(), designer)) {
        garage.setDesigner(designer);
    }
    garageRepository.save(garage);
}
}
```

My Repository:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
public interface GarageRepository extends MongoRepository<Garage, String> {

Optional<Garage> findByCarModel(String carModel);
```

And here's a test:

```
@DisplayName("Garage Service Test")
@DataMongoTest
class GarageServiceTest {

@Mock
private GarageRepository garageRepository;
private GarageService garageService;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    garageService = new GarageService(garageRepository);
}

@Test
@DisplayName("Add Car To Garage Test")
void testAddToGarage() {
    Garage testGarage = new Garage();
    testGarage.setId("630ca281f12905d5f5249f08");
    testGarage.setCarModel("Shelby Cobra");
    testGarage.setHP(485);
    testGarage.setYear(1965);
    testGarage.setDesigner("Carroll Shelby");

    Garage savedGarage = garageRepository.save(testGarage);

    String testedGarage = savedGarage.getCarModel();

    Optional<Garage> garages = garageRepository.findByCarModel("Shelby Cobra");
    assertEquals(testedGarage, garages.toString());
}
```

I'm pretty much green with Unit testing and MongoDB, so I'm not sure where and why this error happens. I've skipped adding the Controller because I think the rest of the code will be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see, garageRepository is instantiated as a mock, so the save method doesn't know at all what to return and returns null by default.
You have to tell Mockito what to return if the `save()`method is called.
This can be achieved by `Mockito.when(...).thenReturn(...)`.

**Your test should test the service, but you don't call a single method of the service!**

On the other hand, it doesn't make sense to query the repository for the saved object as the object is actually **not** saved (again, the repository is a mock, you want to test the service so you want to make sure that the save method of the repository is called correctly). Instead, you should verify that the save() method is called like

```
Mockito.verify(garageRepository).save(testGarage);
```

...or if there is an exception due to an existing object with the same id.
Try the following code (not tested!):

```
@DisplayName("Garage Service Test")
@DataMongoTest
class GarageServiceTest {

@Mock
private GarageRepository garageRepository;
private GarageService garageService;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    //This would be the way to make the mock return sth., 
    //but not really   needed
    //Garage returnObject = new Garage();
    //returnObject.setId("630ca281f12905d5f5249f08");
    //returnObject.set...(...);
    //Mockito.when(garageRepository.save(Mockito.ANY))
    //   .thenReturn(returnObject);
    garageService = new GarageService(garageRepository);
}

@Test
@DisplayName("Add Car To Garage Test")
//This is the 'positive test, object isn't persisted yet
void testAddToGarage() {
    Garage testGarage = new Garage();
    testGarage.setId("630ca281f12905d5f5249f08");
    testGarage.setCarModel("Shelby Cobra");
    testGarage.setHP(485);
    testGarage.setYear(1965);
    testGarage.setDesigner("Carroll Shelby");
    Mockito.when(garageRepository
    .findByCarModel(testGarage.getCarModel()))
    .thenReturn(Optional.empty());
    garageService.addToGarage(testGarage);
    Mockito.verify(garageRepository).save(testGarage);
}

@Test
@DisplayName("Add Car To Garage Test")
//This is the 'negative' test, the repository indicates that the object
//is already persisted
@Expected(IllegalStateException.class)
void testAddToGarageAlreadyPersisted() {
    Garage testGarage = new Garage();
    testGarage.setId("630ca281f12905d5f5249f08");
    testGarage.setCarModel("Shelby Cobra");
    testGarage.setHP(485);
    testGarage.setYear(1965);
    testGarage.setDesigner("Carroll Shelby");
    Mockito.when(garageRepository
    .findByCarModel(testGarage.getCarModel()))
    .thenReturn(Optional.of(testGarage));
    garageService.addToGarage(testGarage);
    Mockito.verify(garageRepository, Mockito.never()).save(testGarage);
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I have one more question, though: I'm getting an error with the `Mockito.when(garageRepository.findByCarModel(testGarage)` line. It requires a String, but the Garage is provided. When I wrap it as a string, then `.thenReturn` turns red and IntelliJ can't resolve it. Is there any other way to get around this?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't read it properly. You are querying the repo by the car model, so it should be `Mockito.when(garageRepository.findByCarModel(testGarage.getCarModel())
        .thenReturn(Optional.empty());`.
I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I've already tried that, but the problem is the same. :(

Comment: Ok, would be better to test the answer in an IDE... I think there is just a closing bracket missing:
Mockito.when(garageRepository.findByCarModel(testGarage.getCarModel()) **)**         .thenReturn(Optional.empty());
Updated the answer again.

Comment: I've added the bracket, it was the first thing I did actually :)) The thing is, when there's just a `.findByCarModel(testGarage).thenReturn(Optional.empty()));` IntelliJ protests that there is provided Garage instead of the String type. But when I wrap it as a String or write it as `.findByCarModel(testGarage.getCarModel()).thenReturn(Optional.empty()));` as you proposed, then `.thenReturn` turns red and IntelliJ can't resolve it.

Comment: Ok, but in your last comment in the second statement, which is correct (testGarage.getCarModel()), the closing bracket is still missing. Copy and paste the statement from my last comment (or the updated answer):

Comment: You were right, the bracket was missing. I'm sorry for making confusion out of it and thank you for the answer, especially for the clarification at the beginning.